# Как сделать отступ в право на 7.45px у SVG&

Tags: html, css

```css
svg path {fill: #000;}
```

```html
<ul id="main-menu-2">
  <li class="main-menu-item-3">
    <a href="#">ЗАГОРОДНЫЙ ДОМ
      <svg width="9" height="6" viewBox="0 0 9 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M8.38247 1.70174L5.05242 5.70383C4.98496 5.78491 4.9005 5.85014 4.80501 5.89492C4.70952 5.93969 4.60534 5.9629 4.49988 5.9629C4.39441 5.9629 4.29024 5.93969 4.19475 5.89492C4.09926 5.85014 4.01479 5.78491 3.94734 5.70383L0.617279 1.70174C0.530005 1.59678 0.474421 1.46915 0.45703 1.33376C0.439639 1.19838 0.461159 1.06084 0.519073 0.937233C0.576987 0.81363 0.668901 0.709073 0.784062 0.635794C0.899223 0.562514 1.03287 0.523543 1.16937 0.523438H7.83039C7.96688 0.523543 8.10053 0.562514 8.21569 0.635794C8.33085 0.709073 8.42277 0.81363 8.48068 0.937233C8.53859 1.06084 8.56011 1.19838 8.54272 1.33376C8.52533 1.46915 8.46975 1.59678 8.38247 1.70174Z" fill="white"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu-item-4">
    <a href="#">ГОРОДСКАЯ КВАРТИРА
      <svg width="9" height="6" viewBox="0 0 9 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M8.38247 1.70174L5.05242 5.70383C4.98496 5.78491 4.9005 5.85014 4.80501 5.89492C4.70952 5.93969 4.60534 5.9629 4.49988 5.9629C4.39441 5.9629 4.29024 5.93969 4.19475 5.89492C4.09926 5.85014 4.01479 5.78491 3.94734 5.70383L0.617279 1.70174C0.530005 1.59678 0.474421 1.46915 0.45703 1.33376C0.439639 1.19838 0.461159 1.06084 0.519073 0.937233C0.576987 0.81363 0.668901 0.709073 0.784062 0.635794C0.899223 0.562514 1.03287 0.523543 1.16937 0.523438H7.83039C7.96688 0.523543 8.10053 0.562514 8.21569 0.635794C8.33085 0.709073 8.42277 0.81363 8.48068 0.937233C8.53859 1.06084 8.56011 1.19838 8.54272 1.33376C8.52533 1.46915 8.46975 1.59678 8.38247 1.70174Z" fill="white"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu-item-4">
    <a href="#">ОБЩЕСТВЕННЫЕ ПРОСТРАНСТВА
      <svg width="9" height="6" viewBox="0 0 9 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M8.38247 1.70174L5.05242 5.70383C4.98496 5.78491 4.9005 5.85014 4.80501 5.89492C4.70952 5.93969 4.60534 5.9629 4.49988 5.9629C4.39441 5.9629 4.29024 5.93969 4.19475 5.89492C4.09926 5.85014 4.01479 5.78491 3.94734 5.70383L0.617279 1.70174C0.530005 1.59678 0.474421 1.46915 0.45703 1.33376C0.439639 1.19838 0.461159 1.06084 0.519073 0.937233C0.576987 0.81363 0.668901 0.709073 0.784062 0.635794C0.899223 0.562514 1.03287 0.523543 1.16937 0.523438H7.83039C7.96688 0.523543 8.10053 0.562514 8.21569 0.635794C8.33085 0.709073 8.42277 0.81363 8.48068 0.937233C8.53859 1.06084 8.56011 1.19838 8.54272 1.33376C8.52533 1.46915 8.46975 1.59678 8.38247 1.70174Z" fill="white"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu-item-4">
    <a href="#">ОБЛИЦОВКА
      <svg width="9" height="6" viewBox="0 0 9 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M8.38247 1.70174L5.05242 5.70383C4.98496 5.78491 4.9005 5.85014 4.80501 5.89492C4.70952 5.93969 4.60534 5.9629 4.49988 5.9629C4.39441 5.9629 4.29024 5.93969 4.19475 5.89492C4.09926 5.85014 4.01479 5.78491 3.94734 5.70383L0.617279 1.70174C0.530005 1.59678 0.474421 1.46915 0.45703 1.33376C0.439639 1.19838 0.461159 1.06084 0.519073 0.937233C0.576987 0.81363 0.668901 0.709073 0.784062 0.635794C0.899223 0.562514 1.03287 0.523543 1.16937 0.523438H7.83039C7.96688 0.523543 8.10053 0.562514 8.21569 0.635794C8.33085 0.709073 8.42277 0.81363 8.48068 0.937233C8.53859 1.06084 8.56011 1.19838 8.54272 1.33376C8.52533 1.46915 8.46975 1.59678 8.38247 1.70174Z" fill="white"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Я перенёс ваш код в сниппет и сделал цвет SVG чёрным, чтобы его видно было, имейте ввиду.

Answer (score 0):

Оберни его в `wrapper` и дай ему стиль

```css
padding-right: 7.45px;
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Артем Аверкин не перепутали с padding-left?

Answer (score 0):

> .. отступ в право на ..

Сместить вправо или всё таки отступ справа..
Если сместить, то в коде ниже оставьте как есть, а если отступ справа, то замените `margin-left` на `margin-right`.

```css
svg path {fill: #000;}

#main-menu-2 .arrow {
  margin-left: 7.45px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="main-menu-2">
  <li class="main-menu-item-3">
    <a href="#">ЗАГОРОДНЫЙ ДОМ
      <svg class="arrow" width="9" height="6" viewBox="0 0 9 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M8.38247 1.70174L5.05242 5.70383C4.98496 5.78491 4.9005 5.85014 4.80501 5.89492C4.70952 5.93969 4.60534 5.9629 4.49988 5.9629C4.39441 5.9629 4.29024 5.93969 4.19475 5.89492C4.09926 5.85014 4.01479 5.78491 3.94734 5.70383L0.617279 1.70174C0.530005 1.59678 0.474421 1.46915 0.45703 1.33376C0.439639 1.19838 0.461159 1.06084 0.519073 0.937233C0.576987 0.81363 0.668901 0.709073 0.784062 0.635794C0.899223 0.562514 1.03287 0.523543 1.16937 0.523438H7.83039C7.96688 0.523543 8.10053 0.562514 8.21569 0.635794C8.33085 0.709073 8.42277 0.81363 8.48068 0.937233C8.53859 1.06084 8.56011 1.19838 8.54272 1.33376C8.52533 1.46915 8.46975 1.59678 8.38247 1.70174Z" fill="white"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu-item-4">
    <a href="#">ГОРОДСКАЯ КВАРТИРА
      <svg class="arrow" width="9" height="6" viewBox="0 0 9 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M8.38247 1.70174L5.05242 5.70383C4.98496 5.78491 4.9005 5.85014 4.80501 5.89492C4.70952 5.93969 4.60534 5.9629 4.49988 5.9629C4.39441 5.9629 4.29024 5.93969 4.19475 5.89492C4.09926 5.85014 4.01479 5.78491 3.94734 5.70383L0.617279 1.70174C0.530005 1.59678 0.474421 1.46915 0.45703 1.33376C0.439639 1.19838 0.461159 1.06084 0.519073 0.937233C0.576987 0.81363 0.668901 0.709073 0.784062 0.635794C0.899223 0.562514 1.03287 0.523543 1.16937 0.523438H7.83039C7.96688 0.523543 8.10053 0.562514 8.21569 0.635794C8.33085 0.709073 8.42277 0.81363 8.48068 0.937233C8.53859 1.06084 8.56011 1.19838 8.54272 1.33376C8.52533 1.46915 8.46975 1.59678 8.38247 1.70174Z" fill="white"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu-item-4">
    <a href="#">ОБЩЕСТВЕННЫЕ ПРОСТРАНСТВА
      <svg class="arrow" width="9" height="6" viewBox="0 0 9 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M8.38247 1.70174L5.05242 5.70383C4.98496 5.78491 4.9005 5.85014 4.80501 5.89492C4.70952 5.93969 4.60534 5.9629 4.49988 5.9629C4.39441 5.9629 4.29024 5.93969 4.19475 5.89492C4.09926 5.85014 4.01479 5.78491 3.94734 5.70383L0.617279 1.70174C0.530005 1.59678 0.474421 1.46915 0.45703 1.33376C0.439639 1.19838 0.461159 1.06084 0.519073 0.937233C0.576987 0.81363 0.668901 0.709073 0.784062 0.635794C0.899223 0.562514 1.03287 0.523543 1.16937 0.523438H7.83039C7.96688 0.523543 8.10053 0.562514 8.21569 0.635794C8.33085 0.709073 8.42277 0.81363 8.48068 0.937233C8.53859 1.06084 8.56011 1.19838 8.54272 1.33376C8.52533 1.46915 8.46975 1.59678 8.38247 1.70174Z" fill="white"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="main-menu-item-4">
    <a href="#">ОБЛИЦОВКА
      <svg class="arrow" width="9" height="6" viewBox="0 0 9 6" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M8.38247 1.70174L5.05242 5.70383C4.98496 5.78491 4.9005 5.85014 4.80501 5.89492C4.70952 5.93969 4.60534 5.9629 4.49988 5.9629C4.39441 5.9629 4.29024 5.93969 4.19475 5.89492C4.09926 5.85014 4.01479 5.78491 3.94734 5.70383L0.617279 1.70174C0.530005 1.59678 0.474421 1.46915 0.45703 1.33376C0.439639 1.19838 0.461159 1.06084 0.519073 0.937233C0.576987 0.81363 0.668901 0.709073 0.784062 0.635794C0.899223 0.562514 1.03287 0.523543 1.16937 0.523438H7.83039C7.96688 0.523543 8.10053 0.562514 8.21569 0.635794C8.33085 0.709073 8.42277 0.81363 8.48068 0.937233C8.53859 1.06084 8.56011 1.19838 8.54272 1.33376C8.52533 1.46915 8.46975 1.59678 8.38247 1.70174Z" fill="white"/>
      </svg>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

P.s.
Чтобы не писать длинные селекторы, я добавил всем `SVG` класс `.arrow`.